# Waiting for WPF Dependency Property to load

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have two Dependency Properties in my Control. Both bind to an `IReadOnlyList` of different types.

```
#region QuestionsProperty
public static readonly DependencyProperty QuestionsProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Questions", typeof(IReadOnlyList<IQuestion>), typeof(DecisionsControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnQuestionsChanged));

public IReadOnlyList<IQuestion> Questions
{
    get { return (IReadOnlyList<IQuestion>)GetValue(QuestionsProperty); }
    set { SetValue(QuestionsProperty, value); }
}

private static void OnQuestionsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    DecisionsControl control = d as DecisionsControl;
    control?.OnQuestionsChanged((IReadOnlyList<IQuestion>)e.OldValue, (IReadOnlyList<IQuestion>)e.NewValue);
}

public void OnQuestionsChanged(IReadOnlyList<IQuestion> oldValue, IReadOnlyList<IQuestion> newValue)
{
    // Both lists needed here
}
#endregion

#region AnswersProperty
public static readonly DependencyProperty AnswersProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Answers", typeof(IReadOnlyList<IAnswer>), typeof(DecisionsControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnAnswersChanged));

public IReadOnlyList<IAnswer> Answers
{
    get { return (IReadOnlyList<IAnswer>)GetValue(AnswersProperty); }
    set { SetValue(AnswersProperty, value); }
}

private static void OnAnswersChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    DecisionsControl control = d as DecisionsControl;
    control?.OnAnswersChanged((IReadOnlyList<IAnswer>)e.OldValue, (IReadOnlyList<IAnswer>)e.NewValue);
}

public void OnAnswersChanged(IReadOnlyList<IAnswer> oldValue, IReadOnlyList<IAnswer> newValue)
{
    // Both lists needed here
}
#endregion
```

The control needs both lists to display its content correctly. The author of the ViewModel could load both properties at will, so I won't know which list is available first.

I'm looking for a way to wait for both lists to be available. I guess the `CoreceValue` method won't help as it isn't able to force a Dependency Property to load a new value from the ViewModel?

Merging the two lists in the ViewModel is not an option as this is a view-related task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not true. Bindings are resolved in a **deterministic way**. If you are using MVVM Pattern, then you should be able to hook it up on `DataContextChanged` event to make sure the ViewModel is now set to the `View` and the moment your `ViewModel` calls `OnPropertyChanged` then that's the time the `OnValueChanged` call back is called.

In your ViewModel, you would want to set `Questions` and `Answers` then explicitly call `OnPropertyChanged` on `Answers` so that you would know when the callback is fired and do your UI logic there.

Comment: I thought of "deterministic" in a way of "the user could change the two properties at will". So I need to design my control in a way where it's irrelevant which propertiy is applied first. I'll edit my question accordingly.

Comment: You have to step back and think again your design and not couple it with each other, because your logic seems not correct if you're saying "user could change two properties at will". What happens if they change answers first, then questions?  You are only handling it at the answers callback. Why do you need two list at the same time? What are you trying to do? Can't it not be on the ViewModel? Is this really a UI logic that you're going to do?